# Can you add/remove points from a polyline in Google Drawings?

Tags: google-drawings

In Google Drawings you can create a polyline, which is a line with points in it where the line can be "bent." Once you've created the polyline with some number of points, you can edit the polyline to change the location and orientation of the points.

Is there a way to add or remove points?

Or do you have to create a new line?

[This Page](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/36zhzhu_coQ;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/authorid$3AAPn2wQd5mpstmqCDCrGpwSJ_SWnt_jIFuUwh7Tqnb8Db_Y6e4kbxf8y45llY41XMuH2cTjEpz48s%7Csort:date%7Cspell:false) from 2010 said this feature doesn't exist.  I couldn't find anything more recent that said one way or another.

Comment: I think this feature-lack is more-or-less proof that Google don't use this software themselves. :-(

Comment: I still use it for one drawing that someone else created back in 2010 or so.  It's gotten no new functionality that I remember in that whole time.  I wouldn't be surprised to learn there was something, but...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this [post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/bRP5RykU-9I;context-place=forum/docs) from 2017 a Google person says it can't be done.

Answer (score 3):

Silly workaround is to export to PPT, edit the slide / points there. Then open the PPT in Google Slides and copy and paste the asset back into your master Google Slide.

Comment: Works as a miracle, thanks!